block tokens being sent to safe wallet
Is there a current guard module code to only allow a list of wallets to send tokens to a Safe wallet?
If there is not would it be possible for me or someone else to develop one?
I have heard of this being done and seen a safe wallet in the wild that does not accept tokens or NFTs. It looks like they are using Safe.

The only official module that we offer is the spending limit module, you could configure this to limit the ability to send out NFT's, this not a guard though. For something more in-depth you would need to develop this yourself or research a little further.
You can find some good examples of other custom modules including guards , at Gnosis github, Gnosis Guild and Yearn and more information on our official developer documentation.
